# Embedded images getting removed by antivirus

Tags: c#, asp.net, mailmessage

I was using the following code to send email messages with embedded images, however it was causing a problem where some messages were sent with the images from the previous messages.

```
using (MailMessage msg = new MailMessage())
            {
                msg.From = new MailAddress(mailFrom);
                msg.To.Add(mail);
                msg.Subject = assunto;
                msg.Body = MSG;
                msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

                //create Alternative HTML view
                AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(MSG, null, "text/html");
                //Add Image - logo
                LinkedResource theEmailImage = null;

                switch (TYPE_MAIL)
                {
                    case "1":
                    case "2":
                    case "3":
                        theEmailImage = new LinkedResource(ImagePath + "logo_rgb.jpg");
                        break;

                    default:
                        theEmailImage = new LinkedResource(ImagePath + "header_report_pt_700.jpg");
                        break;
                }

                theEmailImage.ContentId = "logo";


                //Add the Image to the Alternate view
                htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(theEmailImage);

                //Add Images - email (limit 8)
                LinkedResource img1;
                int count = 0;

                switch (TYPE_MAIL)
                {
                    case "1":
                        string image = "";
                        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                image = Images[i].ToString();
                                img1 = new LinkedResource(AttachmentsPath + image);
                            }
                            catch (Exception)
                            {
                                img1 = new LinkedResource(AttachmentsPath + "empty.png");
                            }

                            img1.ContentId = "img" + (i + 1);
                            htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(img1);
                        }

                        break;
                    case "2":

                        foreach (string imagem in Images)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                img1 = new LinkedResource(AttachmentsPath + imagem);
                            }
                            catch (Exception)
                            {
                                img1 = new LinkedResource(AttachmentsPath + "empty.png");
                            }

                            img1.ContentId = "img" + count;

                            //Add the Image to the Alternate view
                            htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(img1);
                            count++;
                        }

                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                //Add views to the Email Message (all images)
                msg.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

                try
                {
                    //RELAY (configuration on App.config)
                    using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(ServidorSmtp))
                    {
                        smtp.Send(msg);
                        result = "OK";
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    cLog.addItemToLog("E-MAIL FAILED! " + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + " - " + ex);
                }
            }
```

Then as my assumption was that the problem was related to objects not being disposed, I change it a little bit, to:

```
using (var msg = new MailMessage())
            {
                msg.From = new MailAddress(mailFrom);
                msg.To.Add(mail);
                msg.Subject = assunto;
                msg.Body = MSG;
                msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

                //create Alternative HTML view
                using (AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(MSG, null, "text/html"))
                {
                    //Add Image - logo
                    LinkedResource theEmailImage = null;

                    switch (TYPE_MAIL)
                    {
                        case "1":
                        case "2":
                        case "3":
                            theEmailImage = new LinkedResource(ImagePath + "logo_rgb.jpg");
                            break;

                        default:
                            theEmailImage = new LinkedResource(ImagePath + "header_report_pt_700.jpg");
                            break;
                    }

                    theEmailImage.ContentId = "logo";


                    //Add the Image to the Alternate view
                    htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(theEmailImage);

                    //Add Images - email (limit 8)
                    LinkedResource img1;
                    int count = 0;

                    switch (TYPE_MAIL)
                    {
                        case "1":
                            string image = "";
                            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    image = Images[i].ToString();
                                    img1 = new LinkedResource(AttachmentsPath + image);
                                }
                                catch (Exception)
                                {
                                    img1 = new LinkedResource(AttachmentsPath + "empty.png");
                                }

                                img1.ContentId = "img" + (i + 1);
                                htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(img1);
                            }

                            break;
                        case "2":

                            foreach (string imagem in Images)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    img1 = new LinkedResource(AttachmentsPath + imagem);
                                }
                                catch (Exception)
                                {
                                    img1 = new LinkedResource(AttachmentsPath + "empty.png");
                                }

                                img1.ContentId = "img" + count;

                                //Add the Image to the Alternate view
                                htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(img1);
                                count++;
                            }

                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }

                    //Add views to the Email Message (all images)
                    msg.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

                    try
                    {
                        //RELAY (configuration on App.config)
                        using (var smtp = new SmtpClient(ServidorSmtp))
                        {
                            smtp.Send(msg);
                            result = "OK";
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        cLog.addItemToLog("E-MAIL FAILED! " + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + " - " +
                                          ex);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Now, some of the email messages are delivered without the embedded images, the `<img>`tags exist but the images don't.

Now my assumption is that the mail server is blocking some of the embedded images, but I don't know how to test this.

Any suggestion, please?

### UPDATE

Here's a gist with the message HTML (had to edit the message to remove confidential information, however Outlook doesn't allow me to save it back to .EML): https://gist.github.com/julianonunes/477362fe505bd3e49b31038472ae7403

Answer (score 0):

To avoid complications from the server, you can use the following code to locally deliver the message for testing purpose:

```
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("myhost");
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory;
        client.PickupDirectoryLocation = @"C:\temp";
        client.Send(msg);
```

Comment: But this will only prevent the message from being delivered to the users mailbox, or am I wrong?

Comment: I've set the config like you've mentioned and some of the messages are created without attaching the images. But I don't get any exception in the log files. It seems that not all images are being loaded.

Comment: Can you post the resulting eml file content as an edit to your question? (open in notepad). I'm thinking about a problem in the cid's.

Comment: Had to add it as HTML to a gist because of confidential information I had to remove

Comment: It seems you uploaded a word document? This is not a valid eml-file. Could you check the raw eml, the img tags cid's should correspond to multipart boundaries in the message.

Comment: The email can have a hyperlink to documents and videos, they are not embedded in the email. I changed the code to run from a Windows Service instead of the WebApp and now it sends the images correctly.